# GAE Administration Console Custom Pages not showing up

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm working on my first GAE project and I'm having some trouble getting custom pages to show up in the Admin Console. I'm following the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Administration_Console_Custom_Pages) on it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have a feeling it could have something to do with this note:

> Note: Only custom pages defined by the default version will be shown
>   in the Admin Console.

but I'm not entirely sure what they mean (the default version of the app?).

The page URLs work fine if I visit them directly, but the links will not show in the Admin Console sidebar.

**YAML:**

```
application: namegenerator
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

builtins:
- remote_api: on

admin_console:
  pages:
  - name: Manual DB Entry
    url: /admin/db/add
  - name: Clear DB
    url: /admin/db/clear
```

**Python routing:**

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                                ('/vote', SubmitVote),
                                ('/clear_session', ClearUserSession),
                                ('/admin/db/clear', ClearDatabase),
                                ('/admin/db/add', ManualAddToDatabase)],
                             debug=True)
```

This is all being tested and run on my local machine, by the way. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. Did you deploy your application? I think the admin pages will not be shown in your SDK.
By the way: An administrator can change which major deployed version of the application is default using Administration Console: https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: No, I haven't deployed anything; I've only been testing this locally. I can access the Admin pages, but the only options are the Datastore Viewer, I see no custom pages. Would it show that, but not any custom pages locally? That would explain it. I'll deploy and touch back.

Comment: Looks like that did it. Once deployed I see the custom pages in the sidebar. Thanks for the help, I just wish that was mentioned in the docs!